# git clone not working with git:// in virtualbox

Tags: git, github, virtualbox, yocto

I have windows 7 as the host system and ubuntu 16.04 installed via the virtual box. In the Virtual box if I want to clone any git repository , it's not working with git://. To make this work I have used the git config option,

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

And started to access the repositories via https://.

```
evk1206@evk1206-VirtualBox:~/Vinoth$ git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
Cloning into 'poky'...
fatal: repository 'https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/' not found


evk1206@evk1206-VirtualBox:~/Vinoth$ git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky
Cloning into 'poky'...
remote: Counting objects: 342925, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (82825/82825), done.
```

Now I am working with the yocto project and trying to create a bsp layer. When I try to create a bsp layer I am seeing issues with respect to git repository connection.

```
evk1206@evk1206-VirtualBox:~/Yocto/poky/build$ yocto-bsp create mib arm
Checking basic git connectivity...
Couldn't verify git connectivity, exiting

Details: couldn't access git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-dev.git
         (this most likely indicates a network connectivity problem or
         a misconfigured git intallation)
evk1206@evk1206-VirtualBox:~/Yocto/poky/build$
```

Now I don't know how to solve this issue. Any information on this topic would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Yocto project, to work with proxy follow the instructions provided in the following link:

https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Working_Behind_a_Network_Proxy

After following the instructions, the issue is fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that on a non-virtual Ubuntu. You can access the first repository by: 
git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky 
or 
https ://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky 
(different pathes)

With your configuration, "git://" is replaced by "https://" and  you're trying to connect to "https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky", which does not exist (due to missing "/git" in URL path).

Same for the second repository: 
git ://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-dev.git (working) 
https ://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-dev.git (not working, but used due to config) 
https ://git.yoctoproject.org/git/linux-yocto-dev.git (working)

Don't know, why "git://" does not work on your vm, maybe a proxy problem?